# Laravel - Composer Update Error - 4.2 to 5.0

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-4

I was trying to upgrade my my Laravel project from 4.2 to 5.0 using the upgrade support documentation on Laravel website. However, I have hit a roadblock. Can someone help me with the above problem? Any suggestions are appreciated.

brianh@brianh-virtual-machine:~/webroot/productnew$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.0.30

Comment: Hi Karthik, it could be useful to post both the relevant snippet(s) from your composer.json file; as well as the error message text to avoid opening your (large!) image. Thanks!